# socialite laravel 5.2 InvalidStateException

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I implement laravel/socialite with laravel 5.2 and an error occur that is :

"InvalidStateException in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\AbstractProvider.php line 191:"

why was this occur and how am i solve this?